# Почему нейронная сеть со временем не развивается, и результаты не улучшаются

Tags: c#, unity3d, нейронные-сети, искусственный-интеллект

> Как говорится, длиннопост...

#### Вступление

Основываясь на [этом](https://github.com/exoflow/EvolvingNeuralNetwork), а также некоторых видео и статьях, пытаюсь понять систему работы простейших нейронных сетей, которые со временем развиваются и выдают все более точные результаты с каждой итерацией. 
У меня есть платформа; сфера ("игрок");  и — слева и справа от нее — две "еды" — побольше и поменьше. Задача нейронной сети научиться правильно выбирать еду. Нужна та, которая больше.

### Что у меня есть:

- Скрипт еды: содержит 2 публичные переменные: saturation - размер еды, isBenefit - является ли эта еда более предпочтительной перед другой (их, как уже сказал, две: слева и справа от сферы).
- Скрипт NeuralNetwork - нейронная сеть. Я его писал сам, однако смысл его такой же, что и у [оригинального](https://github.com/exoflow/EvolvingNeuralNetwork/blob/master/Assets/Scripts/NeuralNetwork.cs). Даже больше скажу: я вставил оригинальный заместо моего, но нейронка все равно *не* развивалась.
- Скрипт Sphere - сфера. Выглядит он так (по максимуму прокомментировал, чтобы вам было легче читать, лишнее убрал):

```
public class Sphere : MonoBehaviour
{
    public NeuralNetwork Brain { get; set; } // Мозг: нейронная сеть сферы
    public float fitness { get; private set; } // Приспособленность: -0.005 каждый кадр, +0.1 за неверный выбор, +1 за верный выбор еды
    public bool didChooseBenefit { get; private set; } // Правильно ли выбрал еду

    private bool isPlaying; // Бежит ли за едой, или уже прибежал
    private bool hasDecided; // Принял ли уже решение, в какую сторону бежать
    private int direction; // Направление бега

    public void SetBrain (NeuralNetwork myBrain)
    {
        Brain = myBrain;
        isPlaying = true;
        fitness = 0;
    }
    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (isPlaying) // Если еще не нашел еду и играет
        {
            if (!hasDecided) // Если еще не принял решение
            {
                CalculateDistances(); // Осмотреться влево-вправо
                UseBrain(); // Принять решение с помощью нейронки
                hasDecided = true; // Ставим, что уже принял решение
            }
            rb.AddForce(Vector3.right * direction * speed * Time.deltaTime, ForceMode.Force); // Бежим в выбранном с помощью нейронки направлении
            fitness -= 0.005f; // Ежекадровый штраф (penalty)
        }
    }

    private void UseBrain () // Функция использования нейронки
    {
        float[] inputs = CalculateDistances(); // Осматриваемся влево-вправо, inputs - массив из 2 элементов: размер еды слева и справа
        float[] output = Brain.FireNeurons(input); // Пропускаем сквозь нейронную сеть. Получаем output

        direction = output[0]>0 ? 1 : -1; // Направление влево или вправо, при выводе нейронной сети меньше/больше 0.
    }

    private float[] CalculateDistances() // Функция Осмотреться влево-вправо рейкастами
    {
        Vector3 pos = transform.position; // Кэшируем
        float RayLength = 5; // Длина луча

        RaycastHit hitLeft, hitRight;

        Physics.Raycast(pos, -Vector3.right, out hitLeft, RayLength); // Стреляем влево
        Physics.Raycast(pos, Vector3.right, out hitRight, RayLength); // Стреляем вправо

        float[] saturations = {
            hitLeft.transform.GetComponent<Food>().Saturation, // Размер еды слева
            hitRight.transform.GetComponent<Food>().Saturation // Размер еды справа
        };

        return saturations;
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.tag == "Food") // Наткнулся на еду
        {
            if (other.GetComponent<Food>().isBenefit) // Если бОльшая 
            {
                fitness += 1; // Большой приз
                didChooseBenefit = true; // Выбрал правильно
                GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material.color = Color.green; // Подсветка
            }
            else // Если наткнулся на малую еду
            {
                fitness += 0.1f; // Малый приз
                GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material.color = Color.red; // Подсветка
            }

            isPlaying = false; // Остановка всех действий сферы
            GameObject.Find("GameManager").GetComponent<GameManager>().OnSphereFoundFood(); // Запускаем метод проверки: все уже нашли еду (т.е. запускаем новую генерацию) или еще пока нет.

            Destroy(other.gameObject); // Уничтожаем еду
        }
    }
}
```

- Скрипт GameManager - контроллер игры. Также прокомментировал по максимуму для удобства. Лишние перемнные убрал.

```
public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Range(1, 100)] public int GenerationSize; // Кол-во сфер ("игроков") в итерации
    [Range(0.01f, 0.1f)] public float MutationChance; // Шанс мутации каждого участника нового поколения
    private int GenerationNumber; // Номер генерации
    private int countPlaying; // Количество сфер, которые все еще не нашли еду

    private int[] Layers; // Слои нейронки. 
    private List<Sphere> SpheresList; // Список сфер
    private List<NeuralNetwork> PreviousGeneration; // Список сер предыдущего поколения

    private void Start()
    {
        GenerationNumber = 0; // Обнуляем
        Layers = new int[] { 2, 6, 6, 1 }; // Размеры слоев: 2 входных данных (размер еды слева И справа); 2 скрытых слоя по 6 нейронов; 1 выходной нейрон - число от -1 до 1, и если <0 - идти за едой влево, иначе вправо
        StartGeneration(); // Запускаем первую генерацию
    }

    private void StartGeneration () // Запуск генерации
    {
        GenerationNumber++; // Инкрементируем номер генерации
        SpheresList = new List<Sphere>(); // Пока список пустой
        InstantiateSpheres(); // Создаем сферы
        InstantiateFood(); // Создаем еду
    }
    private IEnumerator EndGeneration () // Оканчиваем генерацию
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
        SpheresList.Sort(SortByFitness); // Отсортируем сферы по приспособленности
        SaveGenerationAsPrevious(); // Сохраним мозги наших сфер как, теперь уже, предыдущее поколение
        DestroySpheres(); // Уничтожим наши серы
        DestroyFood(); // Уничтожим оставшуюся еду
        // Creating
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.2f);
        StartGeneration(); // Запускаем новую генерацию
    }

    private void InstantiateSpheres () // Создаем сфер
    {
        SpheresList.Clear(); // Очищаем
        for (int i = 0; i < GenerationSize; i++) // Цикл на нужное количество сфер
        {
            Sphere newSphere = InstantiateSphere(i); // Создаем

            if (GenerationNumber == 1) // Если это первая генерация, то...
                newSphere.SetBrain(new NeuralNetwork(Layers)); // ... вставляем мозги
            else // Если не первая генерация, то...
                newSphere.SetBrain(MutateBrain(i)); // ...Вставляем мозги, которые, возможно, мутировали
        }
        countPlaying = GenerationSize; // Определяем кол-во активных сфер
    }
    private Sphere InstantiateSphere (int index) // Создание одной сферы
    {
        GameObject newSphere = Instantiate(SpherePrefab, new Vector3(0, 1, findPosZ(index)), Quaternion.identity, SpheresContainer); // Спавним
        SpheresList.Add(newSphere.GetComponent<Sphere>()); // Добавляем в список
        return newSphere.GetComponent<Sphere>(); // Возвращаем
    }
    private void InstantiateFood () // Создаем еду
    {
        /* В этой функции я создаю еду: спавню в нужной позиции, задаю цвет, рандомный размер, 
         * определяю какая из вдух "ед" более выгодная: левая или правая.
         * Здесь, на мой взгляд, нет ничего особенного, здесь я никак не зацепляю ни нейронку, ни сферы
         */
    }
    private void SaveGenerationAsPrevious () // Сохраняю поколение как предыдущее
    {
        PreviousGeneration = new List<NeuralNetwork>(); // Обнуляем
        for (int i = 0; i < GenerationSize; i++)
        {
            PreviousGeneration.Add(SpheresList[i].Brain); // По одному добавляем (именно мозги, а не всю сферу, т.к. потом мы ее удалим)
        }
    }
    private void DestroySpheres () { // Уничтожаем сферы 
        /* Здесь я циклом и Destory() уничтожаю еду, потом очищаю массив SpheresList.Clear() */ }
    private void DestroyFood () { // Уничтожаем еду
        /* Ищу по тегам, уничтожаю Destroy() */ }
    private float findPosZ (int index) // Вспомогательная Функция для вычисления позиции по Z
    {
        return 74f - index * 1.5f;
    }

    public void OnSphereFoundFood () // Когда сфера находим еду
    {
        countPlaying--; // Становится на 1 меньше играющих сфер
        if (countPlaying == 0) // Если все сверф уже нашли еду
        {
            StartCoroutine(EndGeneration()); // Оканчиваем генерацию
        }
    }
    private NeuralNetwork MutateBrain (int index) // Мутирование мозгов
    {
        if (index == 0) // Самый первый в новом поколении...
            return new NeuralNetwork(PreviousGeneration[0], 0); // ... прямой наследник победителя в предыдущем поколении
        if (index < GenerationSize * 0.33f) // Первая треть нового поколения - это...
            return new NeuralNetwork(PreviousGeneration[index], MutationChance); // ... мутировавший тот же самый, но в предыдущем поколении
        if (index < GenerationSize * 0.66f) // Вторая треть нового поколения - это...
            return new NeuralNetwork(PreviousGeneration[0], MutationChance); // ... мутировавший победитель предыдущего поколения
        else // Третья треть - это...
            return new NeuralNetwork(PreviousGeneration[1], MutationChance); // ... мутировавшее второе место предыдущего поколения
    }

    private int SortByFitness (Sphere a, Sphere b) // Сортировка по приспособлености
    {
        return -a.fitness.CompareTo(b.fitness); // Сравниваем по приспособленности
    }
}
```

### Как это все работает:

*Да никак это не работает!* 
Нейронка просто не прогрессирует. Я подключил запись количество сфер, которые правильно выбрали еду, в XML документ с помощью `System.XmlSerialization`, после чего построил в Excel график, и не заметил ни малейшего повышения вверх, хотя дал нейронке прогнать более 800 итераций.

### Вопрос:

Что у меня не так? Почему нет улучшений, если в оригинале все работало: птички спокойно пролетали сквозь трубы, причем в первой итерации не пролетел никто, а уже в 20-й летели почти без проблем. Почему у меня не работает?

> Понимаю, что мало кому захочется разбираться в моем коде, однако, знаю, есть в нашем сообществе люди, которые любят провести обшиное исследование чужой проблемы:) Надеюсь на помощь, хотя думаю, кода в вопросе слишком много, поэтмоу потратил много времени, чтобы весь его раскомментировать:)

Comment: А не учиться это как? Не хочет брать большую еду? Просто как идея. Может сферам просто выгодней есть маленькую еду? Попробуйте их наказывать за выбор маленькой еды. В птичках там наказывают за столкновение и поощряют за удачный пролет. А у вас и там и там вы им даете награду. Я думаю надо быть чуть строже)

Comment: @ПавелЕриков Под не учится я имел ввиду, берёт меньшую еду. Сейчас за выбор большой еды я даю +1, за выбор меньшей +0.1. Возможно, нужно действительно давать штраф в -0.1. Попробую, но мне кажется, однако разве нейронка не должна была додуматься, что +1 больше, чем +0.1?

Comment: Я не очень понимаю как у вас все устроено. У вас есть сфера. Справа и слева стоит большая и маленькая. На случайном расстоянии от сферы? И пока сфера не дойдет до любой еды, следующая генерация не начнется?

Comment: @ПавелЕриков Еда стоит справа и слева не одинаково расстоянии. Задача сферы: научиться выбирать направление, в котором нужно бежать. Потом, возможно, я буду рандомизировать расстояние между сферой и едой с разных сторон. Новая генерация начинается, когда все 10 сфер (у каждой свои веса связей между нейронами) найдут еду.

Comment: Ага, понимаете у сферы нет мотивации есть большую еду. Она за маленькую получит бонус и ей нормально будет. То есть сейчас я думаю у вас больше случайный выбор идет, а не что-то осмысленное. Да я думаю единственное решение наказывать за выбор маленькой еды, чтобы появилась мотивация есть большую.

Comment: А есть ли реальная необходимость в нейронке здесь? Ну то есть в чем конкретно привилегия нейронки перед простым поиском  большей еды через тот же оверлап?

Comment: @Andrew Я уже забыл про этот вопрос:) Конечно можно просто перебирать всю еду и находить лучшую по какой-нибудь умной формуле типа `(размер*k)/(расстояние*m)` где к и m коэффициенты, но 7 месяцев назад я хотел это сделать через нейронку с эволюцией. Сейчас мне этот вопрос уже не нужен, честно говоря)

Comment: > NeuralNetwork - нейронная сеть. Я его писал сам Там и кроется проблема. Ты сделал неправильно механизм мутации Нейронной сети.